# Html video is black on android chrome

Tags: html, html5-video

My html videos are just black boxes on chrome 4.2 for android.

This is my code:

```
<video loop autoplay>
        <source src="url-to-image.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="url-to-image.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It works fine on:

- Chrome: desktop and iOS
- Firefox: desktop, iOS, Android
- Safari desktop, iOS

The only browser it doesn't work is chrome for android.

I have also tried to play the video with javascript (video.play()).
If I long-tap on the video, chrome suggests 'save video'.
I am using apache to serve the files.

Any idea? what that can be?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a content-security-policy problem. see http://www.content-security-policy.com. I developped an mobile application for android and ios. This february the images aren't displayed anymore, because android added stricter content policy. With ios app no such issue occurs.

Comment: Hi @SimonSchüpbach. I added `Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"` to my .htaccess. Without success. Any more ideas? :)

Comment: You must add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; media-src *; >` to the header part of your html page

Comment: If it is something else try https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Content-Security-Policy didnt work. Will use the remote debugger now and report back.

Comment: @SimonSchüpbach: I can't really see anything abnormal. I am thinking it is my apache config.

Comment: Did the device send the request? And didn't receive anything? Because if the device didn't send some request, the apache couldn't be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Android chrome doesn't show the first frame of the video as a poster image the same way ios chrome does.

Android chrome doesn't show a play button like ios chrome does unless it is specified on the video element

```
<video controls>
    ...
</video>
```

My suboptimal solution is to activate the controls via JS:

```
    // Turn on controls on mobile chrome
    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0;
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (isAndroid && isChrome) {
        var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');

        [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) {
            video.controls = true;
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately there is no poster image shown on chrome too, so there is no way to have it not be a black box.

[image]